# Laravel / Eloquent : Get only a subJson of a mysql json field

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a mysql database `(MySQL 5.7.1)` with a single table called "***inventory***". This table contains 2 columns :

- **parentId** *{String}*
- **dataInv** *{json}*

So, each entry in my table contains a json data defined as follow:

```
{
    testId : "4",
    lang : "en",
    subTask : {
        inv : {
           hasright : true,
           isNew : false
        }
    }
}
```

In my Inventory model class, i defined :

```
 protected $casts = [
     'dataInv' => 'array',
 ];
```

In my InventoryController, i defined a method to get the "inv" structure for a given parentId:

```
public function getInventoryByParentId($parentId) {
    $inventory = Inventory::where('parentId', $parentId)->first();
    return response()->json($inventory);
}
```

This function works fine, but return the entire structure as json. For example, for the parentId : 4 :

```
{
    parentId : 4,
    dataInv : {
        {
            testId : "4",
            lang : "en",
            subTask : {
                inv : {
                   hasright : true,
                   isNew : false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i want to retrieve only the subJson "inv" :

```
inv : {
    hasright : true,
    isNew : false
}
```

What can I do to retrieve only this json 'inv' by making the filter directly in the first request ? :

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('parentId', $parentId)->first();
```

Comment: Is this behaviour standard, like do you want it to act like this always? Or do you still want to be able to access the whole array? Because when you always want this behaviour, you're looking for accessors / mutators. If you  do not want this behaviour to be standard, you'll have to create a separate method in the model.

Comment: No, tye behaviour of this method should be specific to retireve this json "inv". If i need to get another key, i will duplicate and create a new specific method.

Comment: You may be able to do `select('dataInv->subTask->inv')`. I'm not 100% sure though, as I've only ever used the `->where()` syntax for accessing nested JSON elements in MySQL.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried ti use your method, but it returned a strange json in result : `inventory`->'$.\"data\"'":` ......

Answer (score 0):

You should change what is returned, if you want a different result:

```
public function getInventoryByParentId($parentId) {
    $inventory = Inventory::where('parentId', $parentId)->first();
    return response()->json($inventory->dataInv['subTask']);
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to structure it even better, create a subTask method in your `Inventory` model:

```
public function getSubTaskAttribute() {
    return $this->dataInv['subTask'];
}
```

because than you can just retrieve it easier in your method:

```
public function getInventoryByParentId($parentId) {
    $inventory = Inventory::where('parentId', $parentId)->first();
    return response()->json($inventory->sub_task);
}
```

Comment: Why do this in the model when MySQL provides a JSON struct interface? Just seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy How can i do to interact direclty with the json structure interface from my controller ?